# WCF - Contract Name could not be found in the list of contracts

Tags: wcf

I am relatively new to WCF. However, I need to create a service that exposes data to both Silverlight and AJAX client applications. In an attempt to accomplish this, I have created the following service to serve as a proof of concept:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="urn:MyCompany.MyProject.Services")]
public interface IJsonService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
               RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<String> JsonFindNames();
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace="urn:MyCompany.MyProject.Services")]
public interface IWsService
{
    [OperationContract(Name="FindNames")]
    List<String> WsFindNames();
}


[ServiceBehavior(Name="myService", Namespace="urn:MyCompany.MyProject.Services")]
public class myService : IJsonService, IWsService
{
    public List<String> JsonFindNames() 
        { return FindNames(); }
    public List<String> WsFindNames()
        { return FindNames(name); }
    public List<string> FindNames()
    { 
       List<string> names = List<string>(); 
       names.Add("Alan");
       names.Add("Bill");
       return results; 
    }        
}
```

When I try to access this service, I receive the following error:

The contract name 'myService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'myService'.

What is the cause of this? How do I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your contract is the Interface not the implementation.

Somewhere in the config you have written myService instead of IJsonService.

Answer (score 11):

Remove the namespace from Service name. It will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Modify your web.config
You can find `<services>` tag and below of this tag you have to have two other tag :

`<service ....`
And
`<endpoint ....`

In `<endpoint>` tag you have to reference to interface of your class.

For exampl : If your service class named `CustomerSearch` and your interface named `ICustomerSearch` you have to config like this :

```
  <service name="CustomerSearch" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
  <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ICustomerSearch" 
            behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but my solution was that in my web.config, I was specifying the entire class name (including namespace), whereas WCF would only accept a class name.

This didn't work:

```
<services>
    <service name="BusinessServices.Web.RfsProcessor">
```

This worked:

```
<services>
    <service name="RfsProcessor">
```

Comment: I just removed my namespace, trying to solve the same problem as the OP, and my service vanished.

Comment: This is not correct. The namespace is required. The assembly is **not**.

Answer (score 1):

In the `web.config` file, the `<service` element's `name` attribute needs to be the service type's name with the namespace, but not the assembly (`Namespace1.Namespace2.Class`). The `<endpoint` element's `contract` attribute similarly has namespace-qualified interface type - `Namespace1.Namespace2.Interface`.

This also solves all behavior shenanigans, like `CreateBehavior` not being invokes on `BehaviorExtensionElement`.

Answer (score 1):

I have had that error before for ServiceModel framework 3.5, and I checked my host's config file.  I found it was my cut-and-paste error.  My service was pointing to an old non-existing service than the one I am using.  It starts working again after I corrected these lines like below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <!--<service name="NotUsed.Serv">-->
  <service name="InUse.MyService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8181/LastService" />-->
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8181/InUseService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Note that MyService has to be the name of your contract class in ServiceModel 3.5 BUT IT IS **IMyService** contract interface in Framework 4.0 -->

```
namespace InUse {
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService 
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetList/{PATTERN}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    List<string> GetIDListByPattern(string PATTERN);

}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]    
public class MyService : IMyService
{        
    List<string> MySample = (new _PointRT()).Sample().Select(r=>r._pointXID).ToList();

    public List<string> GetIDListByPattern(string PATTERN) {
        return MySample.Where(x => x.Contains(PATTERN)).ToList();
    }
}
```