# How do I solve the error in my WCF service and proceed on?

Tags: wcf

I am currently developing a C# Windows Form Application that I intend to let it interact with a server. The server will receive posting from a mobile application that I have developed and whenever a posting is received, my Windows Form Application should be notified and give me a notification.

E.g. My mobile application sends an message over to my server. Once my server receives the message, my windows form application should display a new notification showing the content of the message received.

I am now starting to develop my WCF Service and this is what I've done so far

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Posting")]
public interface IPostingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void NotifyAboutPosting(Posting post);
}

[DataContract]
public class Posting
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime PostingTimestamp { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");

        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Posting), baseAddress);

        try
        {

            // Step 3 of the hosting procedure: Add a service endpoint.
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IPostingService),
                new WSHttpBinding(),
                "Posting");


            // Step 4 of the hosting procedure: Enable metadata exchange.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Step 5 of the hosting procedure: Start (and then stop) the service.
            selfHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.
            selfHost.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
            selfHost.Abort();
        }

    }
}
```

regarding the posting class, what I want to ask is that are the methods inside used to get the information from the server?

and how do I proceed on from here after the service is done. (My winform application has been finished and all thats left is to add in this logic to receive the posting whenever the mobile app sends to the server.

and there seems to be a compilation error of

> The contract name '##.IPostingService' could not be found in the list of contracts     implemented by the service '##.Posting'.

could anyone help me with this? thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your *actual* implementation? You have contract (`IPostingService`), data (`Posting`)... but where's code doing *the work*? You seem to lack contract implementation:

```
public class PostingService : IPostingService
{
    public void NotifyAboutPosting(Posting post)
    {
        // do something with post here
    }
}
```

And you register actual worker class (not data) when setting up your host:

```
ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PostingService), baseAddress);
```

Comment: hi. thank you for your reply. so for my case i will do the what the service is meant to do in that class? which in this case checking for new posting from the server?

Comment: @Thomas: yes, in that class you put **service** implementation. However, web services are not best suited for *notifying* (as in observer-subscriber pattern), think of them as a mean to *get* data. So, either your winforms app would have to periodically query web service (*"send me all new messages"* - which can be done), or you'll need to alter your model.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out these likely culprits:

[WCF - Contract Name could not be found in the list of contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077615/wcf-contract-name-could-not-be-found-in-the-list-of-contracts)

[Discussion on Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/fd7c3528-27da-4c2c-8fe2-0b84d4aecf6c)

[Blog post on the issue](http://mrpmorris.blogspot.com/2008/08/contract-name-could-not-be-found-in.html)