# Few basic query regarding entries in config file for WCF service end as a wcf starter

Tags: wcf, configuration, app-config

i am very new in WCF world. i just download a code and saw the wcf service config file but confusion is occuring in my mind regarding entries in config file for WCF service due to my lack of knowledge.i go through some online article but still i have confusion.

### here are my question

1) `<service name="WCFService.Service"`
when service name is required? can i omit the service name and if yes then what kind of problem may occur?

2) can i set any name to service name like abc.xyz or is there is some rule for assigning service name?

3) what is the use of base address? if one omit the base address then what can be problem.
when base address is required.according to below config entries there are two base addresses...why two base address is required. when people give more base addresses? just see the below 2 base address and tell me why people give two base address why not one...is there any specific reason?

4) there are two endpoints one is tcp and another is mex.
if i omit mex base address then service will not be discoverable? if yes that means no one can create proxy from VS IDE or svcutil....am i right.

5) if mex endpoint will be remove then how one can interact with the service....there must be some other way out. if so then tell me how one can interact with service as a client end.

6)

just see the above mex endpoint and tell me can we write mex endpoint url anything like

```
**net.tcp://localhost:1645/MyServer/mex** instead of ChatServer ??
```

actually wcf service hosted in win form project whose name is ChatServer. is this the reason that url becomes **net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex?**

i have seen many time people write mex end point like  and here no url assign to address tag of mex endpoint....why?
when i should write the mex endpoint like above...please explain with example.

7) what is the meaning of /mex....**net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex**
/mex is mandatory and mex is fixed word?

8) now see tcp endpoint

tcp endpoint address has no url rather tcp the word has been assign to address property...why?

can't we assign any valid url to address filed of tcp endpoint??

9) the address field of tcp endpoint will always have the fixed word called "tcp" is it rule or convention.

10) if i need to add another endpoint called wsdualhttp binding then what i need to write in config file

11) suppose some one developing service which will be hosted in IIS but client can be another asp.net web apps and win apps then what he/she need to do?
then what url client should use to create proxy from VS ide? can anyone come with sample config entries.

12) how to write config file if i want that people can create proxy of my service using two url like....one is as sample **net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex** and another one
is **http://localhost:1645/ChatServer/message.svc**

i know my question are very basic but still i am not being able to sort these question.
also guide me how could i have strong knowledge for creating config file entries boldly.

is there any tool which will create right config entries for my service....i am is there any automated apps which will do it on behalf developer. thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="WCFService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfig">

<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/"/>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1648/ChatServer/"/>
  </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  <endpoint address="tcp"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                  contract="ChatService.IChat"/>

 <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

 </service>
 </services>

 <behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
 <behavior name="behaviorConfig">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
  <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
 </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 <bindings>
 <netTcpBinding>
 <binding name="tcpBinding"
                 maxBufferSize="67108864"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                 openTimeout="00:00:10"
                 receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 maxConnections="100">
  <security mode="None">
  </security>
  <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864"
                          maxBytesPerRead="67108864"
                          maxStringContentLength="67108864"/>
  <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"/>
  </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

### MY Edited part start here

3) what common part you are talking about. what common part u have seen in my complete config file...please explain with example.

you said....If you omit base address, you need to specify common part multiple times every time. Multiple base address are required if endpoints are specified for multiple transport protocol

can u please make me understand with example what u have said for omit base address becoz the things not clear to me after reading ur answer for points 3

4) if i disable mex endpoints then how can i create wsdl with svcutil? if i give my service dll then client can decode the code and get my full source code.can u tell me more elaborately what u trying to say for the points 4

12) if i expose two url for consuming my service then asp.net client can create service proxy using tcp url like **net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex ??**
is there will be any problem for web client for using tcp binding. because tcp is state full but web is stateless...that is why i am asking is there will be any problem for web client for using tcp binding url **net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/mex**

13) in my example the mex endpoint look like

but many people create mex end point like

so tell me what is the difference between two mex end point....also tell me when one should go for 1ts mex endpoint and when people go for second mex endpoint

14) in my case if i would write mex end like

and tcp endpoint like

then what would be the result. my service would be discoverable or not.
what address i shoudl use to create service proxy in that case.

if possible please answer my question with mini sample for easy understanding because i am very new in WCF....thanks

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and actually read some WCF learning resources. You've asked several questions in quick succession that can all be answered with a little research and understanding. SO is for "I've looked and looked and can't find the answer", not for "I can't be bothered to look, tell me how to do it".

Answer (score 0):

Your answers one by one

1. Service name is always required. If you omit it in the configuration file, runtime error will occur related to malformed configuration file (with error indicating invalid service name). If you omit it from the code, it will form compile time error.
2. No. Service name should be corresponding to the type that is implementing the service (along with namespace). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077615/wcf-contract-name-could-not-be-found-in-the-list-of-contracts) answer for detail.
3. If multiple end points are defined (like service endpoint, and mex endpoint) with some common part, then common part can be specified in base address tag. Only differential part is then required in endpoint address attribute (usually "" for service endpoint and "mex" for mex endpoint) If you omit base address, you need to specify common part multiple times every time. Multiple base address are required if endpoints are specified for multiple transport protocol (ie different base address for http and net.tcp).
   Example is [here](http://pastebin.com/ncguZBki) with and without baseaddress.
   Common part is "net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer"
4. If you omit mex endpoint, you need to provide the contract information offline to client. As you have mentioned service will not be discoverable. Thus you need to supply the service/data contract information (as WSDL/ library/ source file ) somehow to client application.
   To create client, all you need is contracts and configuration. If mex is available, this information is gathered from mex endpoint. If mex is not available, this information must be made available offline. Example (sending contracts library and configuration by email).
5. Way out is to provide contract information offline (as mentioned in step 4)
6. Yes, but not recommended to avoid ambiguity.
7. No, "mex" is not fixed. It can be anything (as long as URL is valid). "mex" is just unsaid protocol/standard.
8. Endpoint address = baseAddress + address attribute.
   In this case address (of tcp endpoint) = "net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatServer/" + "tcp"
9. It is no convention. It could be anyting (as long as URL is valid).
10. Refer to the link for [wsdualhttpbinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731821.aspx) configuration. However not that since transport protocol is http, you need to provide full address. baseAddress will not be picked up. This is due to [protocol mapping.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/default-protocol-mapping-in-wcf-4-0/)
11. Client app (be it ASP.NET/console/win app/WPF/ any other) need to add [WCF client configuration and proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731745.aspx).
12. If is upto client to decide, which URL they want to use (provided they have access and they are aware). If you want to do it on server side, you may use [Routing service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx) feature (available in WCF 4.0 onwards). 
    I am not sure how web client uses tcp clients (Does security policy allows this?). What ever is the case, exposing two endpoints from server side has no issues on how client will access the endpoints.

13/14 code snippet not visible due to formatting issue.

Comment: some confusion arises....so i again i put some question. please see  MY Edited part in my question at end. thanks